# Angular 5 - Can services replace custom event and property binding?

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm learning angular 5 new and I'm somehow struggling and can't understand 100% the custom event binding (using @Input and @Output) for making communications between components. I knew that services can do the same functionality, so I was thinking about, as I'm not that good at using @input and @output, that I should not waste more time on them and go on until I learn about the services, so I was asking if that OK, would it affect me? Or it can replace them completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services are the more generic approach where you can use them between any components without the need for them to be related at all ( parent / child ). Custom events can only be used between related components and they only go one level deep. So if you have an Output event property it will only always be captured by the immediate parent. It will never bubble up. 
On the other hand you need to be careful when using services with lazy loaded components because you might end up having multiple instances of the same service and have unexpected behaviour.

I believe using service or events is a matter of preference. As long as you understand the restrictions on when you can use them or not and the advantages of each of them. Both approaches have their place.

Regarding your question I would say in the limit yes you could just use services. But I would advise investigating events a bit more because they also they have their advantages.

Answer (score 0):

`@input` and `@output` are used where you have one or two-way binding between a parent and child component.

If you need to have siblings or grandparents and grandchildren communicate, then a 'data' service, which has one or more data objects (as observables) which can be subscribed to, and methods to allow data modification, is a practical solution.

See this [Plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/zNIwBG) for an example of a data service and 3 components - one has an input which calls a method to change data, while the other 2 subscribe to that data.